# Dropdownlist not fetching values for Second and third list Item

Tags: sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns for Showing Categories and Second for showing sub-categories related to the selected categories.

Scenario is. The category values are coming from the tables.And it is fetching properly. The problem is that, when I select the first category the second dropdown shows me the exact subcategory. But when I select the second category, it does not show me the subcategories related to it. 
Please see the Code where I have binded the categories and sub categories to fetch the data.:-

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CategoryName from dbo.CategoriesForMerchant where ParentId is null", conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlCategories.DataSource = dr;
        ddlCategories.Items.Clear();
        ddlCategories.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
        ddlCategories.DataValueField = "CategoryName";
        ddlCategories.DataBind();
        ddlCategories.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Category--", "0"));
        conn.Close();
    }
}
protected void ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CategoriesForMerchant where ParentId=0" + ddlCategories.SelectedIndex + "", conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddlSubCategories.DataSource = dr;
    ddlSubCategories.Items.Clear();
    ddlSubCategories.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
    ddlSubCategories.DataValueField = "CategoryName";
    ddlSubCategories.DataBind();
    ddlSubCategories.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Sub Category--", "NA"));
    conn.Close();
}
```

Also see the SQL Table structure for the same:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[categoriesformerchant] 
         ( 
                      categoryid   INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
                      categoryname NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                      parentid     INT NULL, 
                      CONSTRAINT [pk_CategoriesForMerchant] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (categoryid ASC)
         )goALTER TABLE [dbo].[categoriesformerchant] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_subcategories] FOREIGN KEY(parentid) REFERENCES [dbo].[categoriesformerchant] ([categoryid])goALTER TABLE [dbo].[categoriesformerchant] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_subcategories]go
```

Also see the HTML of the code:-

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqCategory" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCategories" ErrorMessage="Please select the category" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubCategories" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqSubCategory" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlSubCategories" ErrorMessage="Please select the sub-category" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Please paste your HTML]

Comment: First of all remove <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem> from HTML Bcoz you have already wrote that code in the Class file

Comment: Okay, removed from the HTML

Comment: Have you debug your code ? if yes then  What you can see when you are debugging Is any error is coming

Comment: Yes i debugged the code, but it is not showing me any error. Only Null is coming for the second and third list item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64370/discussion-between-hardik-parmar-and-nadeem-khan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this Part

```
string xyz = "";
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCategories.SelectedValue.ToString()))
{
    xyz = ddlCategories.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CategoriesForMerchant where ParentId ='" + xyz + "'", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlSubCategories.DataSource = dr;
ddlSubCategories.Items.Clear();
ddlSubCategories.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
ddlSubCategories.DataValueField = "CategoryName";
ddlSubCategories.DataBind();
ddlSubCategories.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Sub Category--", "0"));
cm.con.Close();
```

n this also

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.CategoriesForMerchant where ParentId is null", conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddlCategories.DataSource = dr;
    ddlCategories.Items.Clear();
    ddlCategories.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
    ddlCategories.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
    ddlCategories.DataBind();
    ddlCategories.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Category--", "0"));
    cm.con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot hardik, for your patience and helping me out. Hats off dude. Its working as a charm..:) :)